# Inserting a database record from an HTML form with jQuery + AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Inserting a database record from an HTML form with jQuery + AJAX is what I'm trying to do but it doesn't seem to work for me.

The HTML looks like this:

```
        <form method="post" id="message-form">
            <textarea id="new-message" name="message" placeholder="Nieuw bericht"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" id="message-sender" name="sender" value="<?=$_SESSION["user_id"]?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="message-recipient" name="recipient" value="<?=$aConversationPartner["id"]?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit-message" id="send-message" value="Verstuur bericht">
        </form>
```

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
       $("#send-message").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if($("#new-message").val()==='')
                {
                    alert("Uw bericht is leeg!");
                    return false;
                }

                var myData = 'message='+ $("#new-message").val() + '&sender=' + $("#message-sender").val() + '&recipient=' + $("#message-recipient").val(); //build a post data structure
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "sendmessage.php",
                    dataType:"text",
                    data:myData,
                    success:function(response){

                        console.log("great succes");

                    }
                });
        });
```

sendmessage.php looks like this:

```
<?

require_once("config.php");
require_once("lib.php");

sendMessage($_POST["sender"], $_POST["recipient"], $_POST["message"], 1);

?>
```

The sendMessage php function works perfectly if I use it without AJAX so that wouldn't be the problem. What is very weird though is that I don't get any console errors at all and the `console.log("great succes");` is fired. I'm new to jQuery + AJAX and desperate for an answer. Please give me an answer I can understand and implement.

Comment: If you open in Firefox, what does firebug tell you?

Comment: I don't use firefox. But I'll have a go with firefox + firebug

Comment: No errors in firebug

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST); in your ajax, does it have data?

Comment: How do I return the data from the var_dump to ajax and log it to the console?

Comment: If you echo something or var_dump or do any output, you will see in firebug in the response of the ajax call what it contains..

Comment: Put `console.log(response)` in the `success` function. You can also look at the raw response in the Network tab of Developer Tools.

Comment: If I log response I get the HTML of my page. Definately something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You should put your data in a JavaScript object.

replace

```
var myData = 'message='+ $("#new-message").val() + '&sender=' + $("#message-sender").val() + '&recipient=' + $("#message-recipient").val();
```

by

```
var myData = {
    message: $("#new-message").val(),
    sender: $("#message-sender").val(),
    recipient: $("#message-recipient").val()
};
```

Comment: That is probably the problem. Serializing the form would be even shorter: `var myData = $('form').serialize();`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :) I used jeroen's method to serialize my form data but seemingly it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping the values in your query string. There are two easy ways to do this with jQuery:

1. Use `var myData = $("#message-form").serialize();` since you're sending all the values from the form.
2. Put the parameters into an object:

   ```
   var myData = {
       message: $("#new-message").val(),
       sender: $("#message-sender").val(),
       recipient: $("#message-recipient").val()
   };
   ```

The plain Javascript way is to call `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var myData = 'message='+ encodeURIComponent($("#new-message").val()) +
    '&sender=' + encodeURIComponent($("#message-sender").val()) + 
    '&recipient=' + encodeURIComponent($("#message-recipient").val());
```

Comment: I used the first method you propose but it still doesn't work :( Might it be something else?